# Not checking anything before or after the string "welcome"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm trying to have javascript match only the string "welcome" with a message containing that however I don't want it to only react when someone says "welcome" exactly. I think I have to use regex for this but I'm not sure and I've been pretty confused on it.

```
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == 'welcome') {
     message.react(reactEmoji)
    }
```

Theres my code. I've tried a few different versions of regex like "/welcome/i" however that did not work

I want something like the image below to get reacted on like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2CSf.png)

Comment: `(/.+welcome.+/i).test(message.content)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: It does not answer my question. https://i.imgur.com/HOrNJnN.png These still do not get reacted on

Comment: @AndyRay Does that need to be inside the if statement?

Comment: You could always keep it simple; ```if (message.content.toLowerCase().indexOf("welcome") > -1) {```.

Comment: Use `String#includes(x)` rather than `String#indexOf(x) > -1` since it's shorter syntax

Answer (score 2):

Get the lowercase version of it and run [`String#includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) on it.

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('welcome')) {
    message.react(reactEmoji)
}
```

Or you can use regex

```js
if (/welcome/i.test(message.content)) {
    message.react(reactEmoji)
}
```